# dynamic nested view with angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

i have an angularjs app with components and i want to add a view as child of another view using ui.router. i honestly dont think that ui.router fully support component, this may happen in upcomping 1.0 version. But in the meanwhile is anything that i can do to use display view dynamically?

this is my $stateProvider (i've done my attempts)

```
 $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url :'/home',
    template :'<home></home>'
  })
  .state('projects', {
    url:'/projects',
    template:   "<project-list></project-list>"
  })
  .state('projectDetails',{
    url:'/:projectId',
    template : '<project-detail projectDetails="projectDetails"></project-detail>'
   , views :{
      'chat':{
          template : '<chat></chat>'

      }
    }
  });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
```

i have created a component in this way:

```
   (function() {
  'use strict';
function ChatController($scope, $element, $attrs, $firebaseArray) {
  var ctrl = this;


  console.log("it works");

}
angular.module('myapp').component('chat', {
  templateUrl: '/app/component/project/chat.html',
  controller: ChatController
});
})(window.angular);
```

and then i've added the view in projectDetails

```
<div ui-view="chat"></div>
```

Comment: ui router has nested states.Have you considered using them?

Comment: OP clearly stated he doesn't know if ui-router supports components. I can verify ngRoute does though.

Comment: i have already tryed with ui.router documentation but is not working. Defining a sub-state and putting ui-view tag where is needed and adding $state.go('substate')

Comment: @David Did the solution I mentioned in answer achieve what you desire?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your requirement is that you have a component called 'Chat' which you want to load in the state 'project-details' as a nested/child view.
As you have already observed ui-router does not support this.

But this can be achieved by making your 'project-details' as a parent state and load other components included as a child state.

[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/kHCxgZ7KErB4nNR5qtjh)

```
angular.module('app', [
  'ui.router'
]).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider.state('home', {
    template: '<home></home>'
  }).state('home.parts', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
      'about-view@home': {
        template: "<about></about>"
      },
      'chat-view@home': {
        template: "<chat></chat>"
      }
    }
  });
}).component('app', {
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
}).component('home', {
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  controller: homeController,
  controllerAs: 'vm'
}).component('about', {
  templateUrl: 'about.html',
  controller: aboutController,
  controllerAs: 'vm'
}).component('chat', {
  templateUrl: 'chat.html',
  controller: chatController,
  controllerAs: 'vm'
});

function chatController() {
  this.name = "chat";
}

function aboutController() {
  this.name = "about";
}

function homeController() {
  this.name = "home";
}
```

Hope this is what you wanted.Please do not add url to the parent state.Consider making it a abstract state.